# Why do regex style line endings no longer work with bulk insert but hex style does?

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

I know there are plenty of examples out there about using 0x0a for ‘ROWTERMINATOR’ but I don’t understand why that is needed. When verifying my files I can see in NP++ that they have either windows or Linux style line endings and can assist accordingly, but that doesn’t seem to work anymore. I’m now forced to use 0x0a and 0x0d.  There’s no mention of any changes that I’ve found, but clearly something is different. I’m on 2022 CU10 if it matters.

——

ETA: By regex style line endings I mean \r , \n and \r\n.

Comment: A lot is explained in the docs: [specify-field-and-row-terminators-sql-server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/specify-field-and-row-terminators-sql-server) and [specify-n-as-a-row-terminator-for-bulk-import](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/specify-field-and-row-terminators-sql-server#specify-n-as-a-row-terminator-for-bulk-import)

Comment: If you show your attempt, we might be able to tell you what the problem is.

Comment: SQL Server tools are not really the best place to deal with inconsistent input formats. If you are receiving data from multiple sources having a mix of CR/LF or LF (newline) line endings, it would be better to use an external text processing tool (or maybe even a PowerShell script) to normalize the data to the expected format before the bulk insert.

Comment: I'm curious to know what you think "regex style line endings" are because neither `BULK INSERT` nor the `bcp.exe` utility have ever supported regex. Can you [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78189042/edit) your question to include a problematic example?